# WCF Current Context is Null

Tags: c#, wcf, logging

I implemented a custom WCF trace listener and writing the logs to a CSV file. In the custom listener I'm trying to access the current request Url.

```
var url =  HttpContext.Current != null ? 
           HttpContext.Current.Request.Url : 
           null;
```

Most of the time this works but eventually `HttpContext.Current` becomes `null`. This mostly happens when a `ServiceLevelReceiveRequest` hits the trace listener.

Is there a reason for this behavior ?

Comment: I have a similar problem if you are a good response i'm interested
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747581/difference-between-weboperationcontext-current-and-httpcontext-current

Answer (score 5):

Here written in [Microsoft's pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx).

### Hosting WCF Services in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode

Although the WCF model is designed to behave consistently across hosting environments and transports, there are often scenarios where an application does not require this degree of flexibility. WCF’s ASP.NET compatibility mode is suitable for scenarios that do not require the ability to host outside of IIS or to communicate over protocols other than HTTP, but that use all of features of the ASP.NET Web application platform.

Unlike the default side-by-side configuration, where the WCF hosting infrastructure intercepts WCF messages and routes them out of the HTTP pipeline, WCF services running in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode participate fully in the ASP.NET HTTP request lifecycle. In compatibility mode, WCF services use the HTTP pipeline through an IHttpHandler implementation, similar to the way requests for ASPX pages and ASMX Web services are handled. As a result, WCF behaves identically to ASMX with respect to the following ASP.NET features:

- HttpContext: WCF services running in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode can
  access Current and its associated state.
- File-based authorization: WCF services running in ASP.NET
  compatibility mode can be secure by attaching file system access
  control lists (ACLs) to the service’s .svc file.
- Configurable URL authorization: ASP.NET’s URL authorization rules are
  enforced for WCF requests when the WCF service is running in ASP.NET
  Compatibility Mode.
- HttpModuleCollection extensibility: Because WCF services running in
  ASP.NET Compatibility Mode participate fully in the ASP.NET HTTP
  request lifecycle, any HTTP module configured in the HTTP pipeline is
  able to operate on WCF requests both before and after service
- ASP.NET Impersonation: WCF services run using the current identity of
  the ASP.NET impersonated thread, which may be different than the IIS
  process identity if ASP.NET impersonation has been enabled for the
  application. If ASP.NET impersonation and WCF impersonation are both
  enabled for a particular service operation, the service
  implementation ultimately runs using the identity obtained from WCF.

WCF’s ASP.NET compatibility mode is enabled at the application level through the following configuration (located in the application’s Web.config file):

```
  <system.serviceModel>        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Hello Zaheer Ahmed,
The service is running in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode. But the context is null only in some cases (Mostly during 'ServiceLevelReceiveRequest' log hits) as i described above. Thank you the reply.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't HttpContext.Current always null for within WCF service? I believe you would want to use OperationContext.Current intsead.

Comment: If the service is hosted in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode then we can access HttpContext.Current

"HttpContext: WCF services running in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode can access Current and its associated state." From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx)

Comment: Got it. Why would you want to if OperationContext provides you what you need?

Comment: Both HttpContext and OperationContext are not available. As i said in the question this happens eventually. Not all the time.